# Shadow of CALayer is not visible on iOS 5.1

Tags: xcode, calayer, shadow

I have a UIView which I set to be my tableView's tableHeaderView using storyboard.

I give this UIView a shadow with the following code during viewDidLoad:

```
_viewHeaderInfo.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
_viewHeaderInfo.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
_viewHeaderInfo.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
```

When I run it in the iPhone 6.0 simulator the shadow shows.
When I run it in the iPhone 5.1 simulator the shadow does **not** show.

Is this not the way to show a shadow? Should I do it differently?
Thanks in advance!

Additional info:

I have some code to hide/show the view using animation on certain user actions. When showing the view (after hiding it first) I noticed that the shadow is showing for as long the animation is running. At the end of the animation the shadow disappears again.
This is the animation code for showing the view:

```
// Get references //
CGFloat h = _viewHeaderInfo.bounds.size.height;
UITableView *tv = self.tableView;


// Move the frame of the View UP by changing the .y value //
_viewHeaderInfo.frame = CGRectMake(0, -h, tv.frame.size.width, h);

// Start animation: adding the View to .tableHeaderView resets the View.frame.y to 0 //
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

    [tv scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
    tv.tableHeaderView = _viewHeaderInfo;

}];
```

Answer (score 1):

UITableView arranges cells and headers vertically to form the table. It simply adds them as subviews to itself. The order in which they are added is not documented (and could possibly change between OS versions).

A layer's shadow is displayed directly below the layer, above previous sibling layers but below following siblings. If the table first adds the header and then the (opaque) cell below it the cell would cover the shadow. If they would be added in reverse order the shadow would be visible.

Order often depends on scrolling direction, simply by which view appears first. But again, this is not documented and subject to change.

Don't depend upon view order in table views.